# Как передать через ajax запрос содержимое поля типа "file"?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вопрос не как передать файл, а как передать имя выбранного файла! Для передачи, как я понял, надо использовать FormData. Но мне нужно получить только имя выбранного файла.

Comment: Получить на стороне клиента или сервера?

Comment: на стороне сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что может помочь:

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById('id').value;
if (fullPath) {
   var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') 
                                               :fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
   var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);

   if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
       filename = filename.substring(1);
   }

alert(filename);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(function () { 
   $('#form').submit(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    var filename = '';

    var fullPath = document.getElementById('id').value; // id елемента где файл input
    if (fullPath) {        
       var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ?fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
       var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);

       if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
          filename = filename.substring(1);
       }
    }

    $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
      url: '/Home/DoIt', 
      data: {
       form: $('#form').serialize(),
       fileName: filename
      }, 
      dataType: 'html', 
      cache: false 
  })
   .done(function (response) { 
      $('#results').html(response) 
   })
   .fail(function (response) { 
         console.log(response); 
         $('#results').html(response) 
      }); 

     }); 
})
```

Comment: Как мне это использовать в
$(function () {
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/DoIt',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false
        }).done(function (response) {
            $('#results').html(response)
            }).fail(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
                $('#results').html(response)
            });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
})

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!